# Bad information in google snippets

Tags: feature-request, google

I recently googled

```
why is cathode labelled with k
```

and here is the result

[image: Google result]

[The link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiKwKeXr8bvAhWeUxUIHWtNC_4QFjABegQIBRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Felectronics.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F65981%2Fwhy-is-the-symbol-for-cathode-a-k&usg=AOvVaw34rmP2aU6ILIMKtMKKX26S) takes you to a question on electronics, which is essentially identical to the question I googled. It has two answers, the accepted one has 15 upvotes, the other has 4 downvotes.

The *featured snippet* shown in the screenshot **is from the downvoted answer**.

As you can imagine, the problem is not unique to Stack Exchange. Try `c is char always signed` for another example.

I wonder what, if anything, can be done to prevent search engines from quoting misinformation from within a page, whether that be from a bad answer or from comments?

Comment: This is a problem with how Google presents data, and not something Stack Exchange can do anything about. Stack Exchange provides Google with [the right markup](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/qapage), and has been providing the information Google could use to avoid this *for years* now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I had a feeling people were going to say "it's a problem with Google". Well for what it's worth I did use their feedback tool.

Comment: Based on Googles own [Rich Results Test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?id=nRSgNnRfH8Fs5IEtRyv7WA) there is nothing Stack Exchange can do any better. Maybe Google doesn't understand a negative upvoteCount?