# Prevent downvoted answers from appearing as Google Snippets

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search-engine

Recently, it's been pointed out that even the lowest scoring answers can get featured in a snippet on Google. This means that part or all of a single answer is shown at the top of Google as a quote, without any context, not even the score — see this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAILv.png). This flies in the face of "good answers rising to the top" since a casual viewer may see only that, assume it is the correct answer, and not visit the full page for details. Sometimes it's all fun and games, but other times answers are downvoted because they're dangerous so we don't want them being highlighted as the most relevant answer.

I think we should keep downvoted answers out of snippets. I don't know the best score threshold but I think there should be one, like -1 or -4.

This may be a contentious stance, since some people believe that either Google or rando Googlers should sort it out themselves. However, snippets like these continue to be a problem, so I think we need to step in.

[Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots-meta-tag#data-nosnippet-attr) shows how individual parts of the page can be blocked from becoming a snippet:

```html
<p>This text can be shown in a snippet
<span data-nosnippet>and this part would not be shown</span>.</p>

<div data-nosnippet>not in snippet</div>
<div data-nosnippet="true">also not in snippet</div>
<div data-nosnippet="false">also not in snippet</div>
<!-- all values are ignored -->

<div data-nosnippet>some text</html>
<!-- unclosed "div" will include all content afterwards -->

<mytag data-nosnippet>some text</mytag>
<!-- NOT VALID: not a span, div, or section -->
```

Can this be done? *Should this be done?*

See:

- [Should we delete this -17 answer that appears as an answer snippet in google search?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12323/42375)
- [Why does Google pick an answer with one of the lowest scores to show as its "snippet" when a search is run?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422825/6083675) (0 score answer shown but not +14 score answer)
- [Google "answering" my search with link to SE, but not showing the top answer(s)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233845/323179) (2 score answer shown but not 300+ score answer)
- [Bad information in google snippets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362455/323179) (duplicate)
- [Disinformation! Quote taken out of context in Google Snippet](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4737/37236) (shows a different problem with snippets which would need a more aggressive solution)